# is it possible to disable automatic type promotion in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, type-promotion

say I have some objective-C like this:

```
- (void) foo:(double)doubleVal;
```

is there a way to make the following code fail to compile:

```
int integerVal;
[self foo:integerVal];
```

while having this code succeed:

```
double doubleVal;
[self foo:doubleVal];
```

?

Ideally I'd be able to do this only for foo, versus globally.

thanks in advance,
Orion

Comment: Curious, why do you want it to fail? `double` can handle any `int` value.

Comment: good Q. it's because I've done a refactor which not only changes the type of this parameter, but also the expected range. Specifically as an int the range was 0 - 255, and as a double it's 0.0 - 1.0.  I have a bunch of code which needs to be converted to match, and it would be great to have the compiler spot all the use-cases for me.

Comment: With that sort of refactoring, I'd keep the old method and then create a new one with a slightly different name. The new one takes the `double` and the old one takes the `int`. This keeps any existing code from breaking. Now you can change code to use the new method (and the new range) as needed. You could even leave all old code alone and change the old method to simply call the new method after converting the `int` to the new `double` range.

Answer (score 0):

no I don't see how you can disable it. an int can be represented as double just fine (for ex.) and I don't think there is a way to disable it.

question remains: Why? Maybe you should reconsider your design

of course you could kinda 'fake it' by using custom number types all over the place :D
e.g. if you have struct myInt and a struct myDouble it won't change types

Comment: thanks for the answer - re why, see my comment above. I'm not sure introducing a custom number type actually catches this. - the compiler will just auto-promote between the custom types as well.

Comment: no it won't if they are different .. e.g. if you have struct myInt and a struct myDouble it won't change types

Comment: ah I see what you mean. yeah, that could be an approach, thanks!